# incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

class Main {  
  public static int TimeConvert(int num) { 

    int t;int n;
    t = num % 60;
    n = num / 60;

    return n + ":" + t;

  } 

  public static void main (String[] args) {  
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(TimeConvert(s.nextLine())); 
  }   

}
```

Im looking to output on the screen using the return method the answer of num / 60 with a : then outputting the answer of num % 60. It will look something like this.. (User enters number 124) then it outputs 2:4 (hours:minutes). It works if I System.out it but not when I return it.  I get the error message...

```
Main.java:11: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int

return n + ":" + t;      

        ^
1 error
```

How can i return (int):(int)?

Answer (score 2):

> How can i return (int):(int)?

There is no `(int):(int)` data type. And you don't need one anyway, you have a `String` in the middle, so return a `String`. Change,

```
public static int TimeConvert(int num)
```

to

```
public static String TimeConvert(int num)
```

Also, you should follow Java naming conventions. Methods start with a lower class letter, your method looks like a class. Finally, I'd put the verb first. Like,

```
public static String convertTime(int num)
```

Finally, if you can use Java built-in functions, I would prefer [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) over hard-coding magic numbers. That is

```
public static String convertTime(int num) {
    long minutes = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(num);
    return String.format("%d:%d", minutes, 
            num - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(minutes));
}
```